# how to convert Token data type of my access token into String data type

Tags: scribe

Scribe gives access token having data type **Token** .
But restFB api for accessing facebook in java requied token in the datatype **String**.
So how can i convert Token data type into String.?

Answer (score 0):

The token class has 3 useful methods:

- getToken ( returns the access/request token )
- getSecret ( returns the access/request token_secret )
- getRawResponse ( returns the full http response )

Don't know what you mean by "datatype String" but you should be able to extract the information you need from these.